# php/mysql update a table and insert new record where no match found

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update a table based on the values from another table. If no record exists, then insert as new record. This code updates correctly but does not insert where records do no exist.

```
$results_google = mysql_query("upadate google set                
    Description = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim(addslashes(strip_tags($row_first['product_description']))))."',
    Manufacturer = '".$row_first['product_vendor']."',
    Price = '".$row_first['product_price']."',                
    Title ='".$row_first['product_title']."'
    WHERE product_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_id'])."';");
if(!$results_google) {      
    $google = "insert into `google`(`product_id`,`id`,`Description`,`Link`,`Manufacturer`,`Title`,
        `Price`,`Shipping_Weight`,`Image_Link`,`Brand`,`inv_id`)
        VALUES (
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_id'])."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_id'])."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags(addslashes($row_first['product_description']))))."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_link'])."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_vendor'])."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_title'])."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_price'])."',                             
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['weight'])."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['image_link'])."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_first['product_vendor'])."',
        '$inventory_id')";
    mysql_query ($google) or die("google".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: To have 'INSERT if not exists, UPDATE if exists', either use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) or [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: How is this relevant to PHP5?

Comment: you wrote "upadate" at line 1, can you indent correctly your code ?

Comment: And don't build SQL from strings, your code is not readable and probably not even secure.

Comment: @Konerak: In 99% of the cases `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is prefered because `REPLACE` would fragment the table data (since it actually does a delete and insert), and probably default all fields that isn't inserted.

Comment: Thanks pal. I'm trying it out now. If you have a psuedocode, you can post it too.

Comment: @Awea: thanks for the correction. I'm trying to see if it was due to that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to insert a row or update it if it already exists, you need to look into `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will only check UNIQUE indexes or primary keys, so make sure the fields that will differ to cause an additional row are marked as unique (or you can do a multi-column unique index).

Read the [documentation for INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: That does not answer the question and it was already mentioned in a comment.

Comment: I was looking up the URL for my answer before the comments appeared, but yes, Konerak's comment also explains what to do. I answered the question of what he wants to do, but I didn't correct his code. Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will force karto to rewrite the entire thing anyway.

Comment: The title of the question is "php/mysql update a table and insert new record where no match found." That's the purpose of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Konerak's comment is really the right way to go, in combination with prepared statements and knowing your data (casting to `ints` for ints, using string functions for strings, etc.), I will answer the question as to why your code is not working as expected.

You are using an update query with a `WHERE` statement. If no matching row is found, no row is updated but the query does not return false because [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) only returns false on error and not finding a row to update is not an error. So as long as your query is valid, your `if` statement will always be false.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comment below, you can use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to check if no row was updated:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0)
{
  // insert a record
}
```

but I would really recommend going the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and prepared statements way.

Comment: This is not exactly correct. mysql_affected_rows returns 0 if a matching key was found, but the row was not altered because the new value is the same as the old value. If you put a normal insert in the if clause, you will get a duplicate key error if this happens. You either need to "insert ignore", or use "on duplicate key update".